# What exactly is meant by a "copy of a graph"?

Tags: graph-theory

I've searched for a clear definition, but all of the notes I find seem to use the term like it has been introduced at some point (which they did not). Can anybody explain to me what that is supposed to be?

Example: "Indeed, $n \choose 4$ $2^{-5}$ is the expected number of monochromatic copies of $K_4$ in a random $2$-coloring of $K_n$, and hence a coloring as above exists."

Comment: It would probably help if you showed us how it's used in a sentence. I suspect, without having read any examples, that they mean exactly what they say: a copy of a graph is another graph that is entirely equal in all respects.

Comment: Probably an isomorphic copy of some graph occurring as a subgraph.

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "copy" is partly informal here, in that it is left to the reader to determine the exact technical meaning that makes sense in the context.

In your example, a more explicit way of expressing the intended meaning would be "... the number of monochromatic subgraphs isomorphic to $K_4$ in a random 2-coloring ...".